# How do I do full text search in a mongo join?

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to perform a join between two collections using a $match that includes a $text on the joined table.  Here is the pipeline expression passed to aggregate()

```json
[
{ $lookup : {
   from: 'events',
   localField : 'chat_id',
   foreignField : 'chat_id',
   pipeline: [{ $match : { $text: { $search: "two"} } }],
   as: 'events'
}}, 
{ $match: { $expr : {$gt : [ { $size : '$events'} , 0 ]} }}, 
{$project: { annotations: 0, events: 0}}, { '$sort': { 'chat_begin_ts':1} }
]
```

But when I do this, I get the following

> mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 17313
> (Location17313): '$match with $text is only allowed as the first
> pipeline stage' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok":
> 0.0, "errmsg": "$match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline stage", "code": 17313, "codeName": "Location17313"}

But of course, the $match/$text IS in the first stage of the $lookup. Other joins not using $text seem to work, as with the following pipeline definition

```json
[{ $lookup : {
   from: 'events',
   localField : 'chat_id',
   foreignField : 'chat_id',
   pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr : { $eq : [ "$event_type", "etype1"]}}}],
   as: 'events'
} 
...
```

I am using mongo 3.12.14 Java driver and 5.0.7 server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mongo Atlas you can try [`$unionWith` query with `$search`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/search-with-unionwith/#std-label-search-with-unionwith-tutorial)

```
db.chats.aggregate([
{
  "$search": {
    "text": {
      "query": "foobar",
      "path": "name"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "score": {
      "$meta": "searchScore"
    },
    "_id": 0,
    "docType": {$literal: "chat"},
    "name": 1
  }
},
{
  "$unionWith": {
    "coll": "events",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$search": {
          "text": {
            "query": "foobar",
            "path": "message"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "$project": {
          "score": {
            "$meta": "searchScore"
          },
          "docType": {$literal: "event"},
          "message": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
])
```

---

Alternatively if you're not using Atlas you can reverse your lookup and first filter all the documents in `events` collections.
And then lookup with the other collection, let's call it `chats`.
After that you can transfrom the data to what you'd like to get:

```
db.events.aggregate([
{ $match: { $text: { $search: "two"} } },
{ $match: { event_type: "etype1" } },
{ $lookup: {
   from: 'chats',
   localField : 'chat_id',
   foreignField : 'chat_id',
   as: 'chat'
}},
{ $unwind: '$chat' },
{ $groupBy: {
  _id: { chat_id: '$chat_id' },
  chat: { $first: '$chat' },
  chat_begin_ts: { $first: '$chat_begin_ts' },
},
{ '$sort': { 'chat_begin_ts':1}
]);
```

Comment: Thank you and yes I suppose you are correct, but what if you need to do the text search in the join, for example, if doing a text search in each collection.  Is there even a way of doing that with Mongo?

Comment: @DavidWood this can be done with Mongo Atlas search. If you're not limited to using regular full text search and run your deployment on Atlas, this is possible. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/search-with-unionwith/#std-label-search-with-unionwith-tutorial

Comment: @DavidWood I've updated my answer, I hope it'll help, please have a look